# How to submit a form when the Enter Key on a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to submit the content in the textarea as shown below by just hitting the `Enter` key on any keyboard on planet earth. When the user hits the `Shift+Enter` key, the caret has to go to a new line and on hitting `Enter` the submitted textarea content should have the new lines created when the `Shift+Enter` was pressed. The content of the textarea should be inserted after the the div with class `commentWrap` but the last submitted comment should apear last and vice verser.

I want this solution to work in all browsers.

```
<div class="commentWrap"></div>

<textarea id="test"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").keypress(function(e) {
            var textVal = $(this).val();
            if(e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
                //What should I really do here
            }
            else if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey) {
                e.preventDefault(); //Stops enter from creating a new line
                //this.form.submit(); //or ajax submit
                if (this.value ==="") {
                    alert("Hey punk! Put some text before you hit enter.");
                }else {
                    alert(textVal);
                    $("<div class='comment'>"+ textVal +"</div>").insertAfter('.commentWrap');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? I don't see a question in there.

Comment: As you don't have a form, are you planning on using ajax to submit the textareas value ?

Comment: The problem is that when I press `Shift+Enter`, on submit the line break is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

> //What should I really do here

Nothing I think, all browsers will insert a new line if shift + enter was pressed so you can just return true;

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a submit button that is used to submit the form you can simply trigger the click handler.

```
    $("#submitButton").click();
```